# What is Better for Prediction Error: Covariance Penalties or a Test Set?

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, aic

I'm reading *Computer Age Statistical Inference* by Efron and Hastie, two statisticians I have a lot of respect for.

Section 12.3 discusses Mallows' $C_{p}$, Akaike's information criteria (AIC), and Stein's unbiased risk estimator (SURE), which the authors collectively call "Covariance Penalties", for estimating prediction error. They conclude this section with the following recommendation.

> Covariance penalty estimates, when believable parametric models are available, should be preferred to cross-validation.

Is this understanding conventional? I have always preferred cross-validated prediction error as a primary measure, and I throw in a covariance penalty measure for additional insight if I'm reasonably confident in my modeling assumptions. I guess my key gripe here is the authors' use of the word *believable*. Before reading this passage, my understanding was that cross-validated prediction error should be preferred when it is available because it does not require the additional assumption of a statistical model. Even when the model seems believable, it is unlikely that it holds in every detail, and for that reason cross-validated prediction error is more reliable.

The authors give some justification for this claim by demonstrating that a poorly chosen test set is not a good measure of prediction error. This isn't too surprising. I'm interested in hearing others' opinion on the topic and their justification.